# access scope inside windowTemplateUrl in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a windowTemplateUrl for my modal as follow

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" data-ng-click="close($event)">
    <div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}">
        <div class="modal-content square-btn">
            <div class="modal-header custom-modal-header square-btn">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel($event)">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}--</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" modal-transclude>

            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my js code is as follow

```
$modal.open({
            windowTemplateUrl: 'templates/common/modal.html',            
            templateUrl: 'templates/jobs/create-job-modal.html',
            resolve: {
                modalTitle: function(){
                    return 'Create new position';
                }
            },
            controller: ['$scope', 'modalTitle', function( $scope, modalTitle ) {
                $scope.modalTitle = modalTitle;
            }]
        });
```

But it seems that my scope is not accessible from `modal.html` template. But i can access it from `create-job-modal.html` template. I need it inside modal.html.

How can i achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try manually setting `ng-controller` in the html for the controller you want.

Comment: right now i am doing the job using $rootScope & assigning a controller for modal-header part. But i think there is be a better & straight forward approach to do this.

Comment: Try using a separate controller for the modal and attaching it to the `div` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of counter-intuitive but the scope of the controller is actually the parent scope of the windowTemplate.
So you can access modalTitle by doing $parent.modalTitle in your windowTemplate.