# How can I style 2 ui-bootstrap modals differently?

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 modals that I'd like to style differently at the modal-dialog level.  I'm not sure how to do it.  It seems that if I apply a style that I think should only apply to one, it applies to both of them.  One modal template is passed as an HTML string, the other is passed as a script/ngTemplate that is part of the partial page that the controller runs on, if that difference matters.  The one that is passed as a string has an ID on the root div, and the CSS that is applied to that doesn't seem to work.  But if I have just a .modal-dialog in my css, that is applied to both modals, as I would expect it to.  In the Chrome debugger, the #ErrorModal selector is greyed out, so it does see it, it's just not applying it, even with an !important, and I'm not sure why.  When either modal is displayed, the HTML looks similar, in that the one that uses the template doesn't contain any of the classes from the parent div that it's wrapped in.  One of the main things I want to do is set the background-color of the error modal to white, but leave my other one opaque.

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854035/is-it-possible-to-customize-style-of-bootstrap-modal), but I don't know that it will let me apply styles 'above' the template.

My css-fu isn't very strong, nor is my Angular, but it seems like the specificity should make it apply.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an option you can pass to the modal, `windowTemplateUrl`.  I haven't found great documentation for it, but I was able to cobble something together using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702427/access-scope-inside-windowtemplateurl-in-angular) as a springboard.